# Read numeric data from oracle table in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess, idbcommand

I am trying to write c# function to read some data from oracle table

My functions:

```
public static writeConsole(string query, string connectionString, string driver)
{
    //driver = Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
    using (var conn = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(driver).CreateConnection())
    {
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = query;

            foreach (var item in ReadDouble(cmd))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
private static IEnumerable<double> ReadDouble(IDbCommand cmd)
{
    using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (r.Read())
            yield return r.GetDouble(0);
    }
}
```

There is no problem in connection, nor executing query.

When I read data from oracle table in type number(9) it returns proper values I am expecting.

When I read data from table, where type is number(9,2) it returns empty value (like empty table).

Notice: This is only sample of the code. It has to be written using IDb interfaces

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it is problem with type mapping. Try this:

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featSafeType.htm#i1008428

And this:

https://community.oracle.com/message/3582080

Comment: Useful information to improve the quality of your answer: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static writeConsole(string query, string connectionString, string driver)
{
    //driver = Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
    using (var conn = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(driver).CreateConnection())
    {
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0]+"");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can Try

```
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();
        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0]+"");
            }
```

Comment: Sorry, but the script returns false for reader.Read(). There is problem in Read() not in console write part

Comment: You should check yours query. because Read method the result is Query

Comment: There is no problem in query. Testing query is only select num from test1 or select num from test2, where num in test1 is number(9) and num in test2 is number(9,2)